# paracol: have column-wise floats numbered in order of appearance?

Tags: floats, paracol

I'm typesetting (non-synchronized) parallel columns with `paracol.sty` – a translation actually, one language in the left, the other in the right column. The document contains a lot of "column-wise" floats (that is, floats typeset within a column). As `paracol` reads and processes the whole left column (stretching over various pages) before the right column, all the floats in the left column are numbered before the floats in the right column, even when they appear on a later page. This leads to the floats appearing in an unordered way given the linear appearance in the flow of the pages.

Is there a way to work around this? I need to keep the floats as column-wise floats (so they may not break the two-column layout).

Is there a way to modify the counter mechanism to have the numbers follow the order of appearance? Or at least in order of *pages*? (that is, within a page I don't mind if all left column floats are numbered before the right column floats, but this should not stretch across pages)

Or do I have to implement a "manual" numbering using `\setcounter{figure}{0}` etc?

Thanks a lot!

PS: I know that the `paracol` manual says that this "problem" occurs. But maybe someone has an idea how to resolve it.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\globalcounter{figure}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \begin{figure}[t] 
        \caption{The caption}
        \label{Label1}
    \end{figure}
    \lipsum[2]

    \switchcolumn

    \begin{figure}[t]
        \caption{The caption}
        \label{Label2}
    \end{figure}
    \lipsum[1-3]

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

The following example shows figure 2 appearing before figure 1 if following the order of the pages.

[image]

Comment: The `paracol` manual explicitly states that `t` - float environments are problematic in synchronizing columns. You have `t` - float environments ;-) (requires `caption` package)

Comment: Yes I know, the manual mentions this. So it's not a bug report, but maybe someone has a solution! BTW, the problem doesn't depend on the 't' positioning, it also occurs with 'h'. The problem is that numbers are given in order of source code and the *whole* left column is processed and broken across pages before the right column is processed.

Comment: Do you use `hyperref` and links? If not, there might be a easy solution.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `\globalcounter{figure}` statement?

Comment: Removing the statement would produce separate numbering of the floats in each column, which is not what I'm looking for. And yes, alas, I'm using `hyperref`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fix `\caption`, `\label` and `\listoffigures`.  Note that it takes (at least) two runs.

One must add `\useparafig` before `\caption`.  It redefines `\thefigure` for the rest of the figure environment (or current group).

It works by creating a translation table between `\thefigure` and the order in which the figures actually appear (`\theparafig`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\globalcounter{figure}

\newcounter{parafig}

\newcommand{\newparafig}[1]{\stepcounter{parafig}%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname parafig#1\endcsname{\theparafig}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\useparafig}{\protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\newparafig{\thefigure}}%
  \@ifundefined{parafig\thefigure}{}%
  {\edef\parafig{\csname parafig\thefigure\endcsname}%
   \let\thefigure=\parafig}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures\newpage
\sloppy
\begin{paracol}{2}
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \begin{figure}[t]
        \useparafig
        \caption{The caption}
        \label{Label1}
    \end{figure}
    \lipsum[2]

    \switchcolumn

    \begin{figure}[t]
        \useparafig
        \caption{The caption}
        \label{Label2}
    \end{figure}
    \lipsum[1-3]

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an amazing solution! That makes `paracol` a very powerful solution for publishing two-column translations.